# Apply Json data to Barchart -Plotly

Tags: angularjs, json, bar-chart, plotly

I am using Plotly to draw bar graph . Currently i am giving data hardcoded. But now i want to gicve json data to chart . How can we parse it and use it . Kindly help as i am new to json.

//Below is plotly code:

```
   var trace1 = {
       x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
       y: [20, 14, 23],
       name: 'SF Zoo',
       type: 'bar'
   };
   var trace2 = {
       x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
       y: [12, 18, 29],
       name: 'LA Zoo',
       type: 'bar'
   };
   var data = [trace1, trace2];
   var layout = {
       barmode: 'group'
   };
   Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Now i want parson JSON data and assign value from json data to x and y-axis.

```
[{"PartList.PartList.COID":"3D3DB2BCF8A50D94", "PartList.PartList.COMPID":3030, "PartList.PartList.C_VERSION":1, "PartList.PartList.NATCO":"null"}, {"PartList.PartList.COID":"3D3DB2BCF8A50D9F", "PartList.PartList.COMPID":3030, "PartList.PartList.C_VERSION":1, "PartList.PartList.NATCO":"null"}, {"PartList.PartList.COID":"3D3DB2BCF8A50D9F", "PartList.PartList.COMPID":3030, "PartList.PartList.C_VERSION":1, "PartList.PartList.NATCO":"null"}]
```

Comment: You have 3 objects in JSON. Do you want to spit it to 3 traces? or to 3 points?

Comment: Yes it has three objects only, it is raw data actually i want to know logic about how to parse data from json and applied to graph

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how to do it, please change the variable names in X and Y axis to anything you want. Please let me know if there are any issues.

<kbd>**`JSFiddle Demo`**</kbd>

**Code:**

```
var data = [{"PartList.PartList.COID":"3D3DB2BCF8A50D94", "PartList.PartList.COMPID":3030, "PartList.PartList.C_VERSION":1, "PartList.PartList.NATCO":"null"}, {"PartList.PartList.COID":"3D3DB2BCF8A50D9F", "PartList.PartList.COMPID":3030, "PartList.PartList.C_VERSION":1, "PartList.PartList.NATCO":"null"}, {"PartList.PartList.COID":"3D3DB2BCF8A50D9F", "PartList.PartList.COMPID":3030, "PartList.PartList.C_VERSION":1, "PartList.PartList.NATCO":"null"}]

var traces = [];
data.forEach(function(val){
    var trace = {
    x: [val["PartList.PartList.COMPID"]],
    y: [val["PartList.PartList.C_VERSION"]],
    name: val["PartList.PartList.COID"],
    type: 'bar'
  };
  traces.push(trace);
});
console.log(traces);
   var layout = {
       barmode: 'group'
   };
Plotly.newPlot('tester', traces, layout);
```